# Is there a way to go through inner objects with less verbosity

Tags: java

I'm needing to through some inner objects like this (I always need the index 0):

```
e1.getElements().get(0).getVariantOption().getPointOfServices().sort(comparator);
```

I'm checking all empty list and nulls with this piece of code.

```
if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(e1.getElements()) && e1.getElements().get(0).getVariantOption() != null &&
            CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(e1.getElements().get(0).getVariantOption().getPointOfServices()))
    {
        e1.getElements().get(0).getVariantOption().getPointOfServices().sort(comparator);
    }
```

Is there a way in Java to reach this same without repeating all that times the e1.getElements...? I feel like this code is pretty verbose.

Comment: Sure.  Save things into variables.  And use `!collection.isEmpty()` instead of `CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty()`.  If you have nulls, that's a bug, and you _should_ throw.

Comment: Why you say that having a null is a bug?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?  There's almost never a good reason to have a null instead of an empty collection.  This code example demonstrates that you want to treat them the same, anyway.

Comment: You aren't gaining anything by using "null" to represent things like "no results present", and definitely the code becomes more complicated with lots of "proceed only if results are not null" checks. On the other hand, you can easily represent "no results" with an empty collection. And every caller can easily handle empty collection. For all things in collection, do my special xyz handling, doesn't matter if there are 1,000 things or 0; my xyz handling stays the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be simplified to this:

```
VariantOption option = CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(e1.getElements()) ? 
                    e1.getElements().get(0).getVariantOption() : null;

if (option != null && CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(option.getPointOfServices()))
{
    option.getPointOfServices().sort(comparator);
}
```

I assumed `getVariantOption` function to return an object of class `VariantOption`, but modify it accordingly.